# How to disable or hide the system bar on android 3.x

Tags: android, android-widget, android-3.0-honeycomb, widget, root-access

I would like to know if it's possible to remove/hide/disable the bottom menu bar that always shown on android 3.x .
if not - at least if it's possible to hide the opening of the widget bar or disable the core widgets.
programatically or not - I must deny access to the bottom menu when my app is foreground.

please help.
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible to remove/hide/disable the bottom menu bar that always shown on android 3.x .

No, you cannot remove/hide/disable the system bar.

> if not - at least if it's possible to hide the opening of the widget bar or disable the core widgets

There is no concept of a "widget bar" or "core widgets" in Android, so I do not know what you are referring to here.

> I must deny access to the bottom menu when my app is foreground.

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

You are welcome to build your own custom firmware that you load on your own custom hardware that contains this "feature".

Comment: thanx for the fast answer. when I've wrote "widget bar" - I meant to the menu which displaying widgets when clicking the arrow on the system bar

Comment: @TalKanel: The only "arrow" I see on an Android 3.x (Motorola XOOM) system bar is the BACK button. What you are describing might be unique to your particular hardware, or perhaps they are using alternative icons to access recent tasks, or the notification/device panel on the right, or something.

Comment: just wanted let you know I've read a post about how to programmatically remove system bar in Honeycomb, and I saw there your comment also... It's working, exactly as promised, altough you said it's not possible.   so I'm not going to share the link cause I understand it consider a security hole. I just want you to know I need this from good reasons: I'm developing an educational product which been use directly on 30-40 tablets, not going to be published on market at all, so I really need to control the device completely

Comment: @TalKanel: The right answer for your scenario is to use your own firmware.